# Why do I get an undefined index for signed_request in my facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I am attempting a test app to learn on facebook.  I am using this code from the facebook developer [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/):

```
 <?php 

     $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

     $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

When I run this I get:

```
Message: Undefined index: signed_request
```

I am using this in Codeigniter.  I have no idea if that matters..  When I run this it uses the $auth_url and return:

http://mydomain.com/responsepage?code=biglongstring

so I know I am getting to facebook and getting something...

In that string url returned is a variable named "code."  I tried to change the $_REQUEST object to look for "code" but it gives the same error.

It does redirect me back to my response page after it briefly displays the error because the "user_id" element is empty.  It is empty because signed_request is not present in the url sent back.

What am I doing wrong?  It should go to facebook, ask for me to allow the app, display the user_id.  For some reason the signed_request just isn't there.

Thank you.

EDIT:  I'm looking at this again.  Where does it ever actually go out and use that URL?

EDIT:  If I use the $auth_url manually, pasting it in the address of the browser it redirects back to my response page with no problem.  Of course, I did not see a variable named signed_request, just "code" so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Are you using this code *inside* Facebook iframe or outside in a standalone website?

Comment: I created it as an app.  So I thought that meant I use iFrame.  I did not select the my own website thing.

Comment: So you are being redirected to *outside* Facebook?

Comment: Yes.  I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: But, It is set up as app on facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay it seems that you are using your *Canvas URL* in the `$canvas_page` variable which is **wrong**. You need to use the *Canvas Page* which is something like: `http://apps.facebook.com/appnamespace`

This way, your app will open *inside* the iframe and Facebook will be able to send you the `signed_request`

Comment: oh crap I'm dumb.  I was going to my webpage instead of apps.facebook.com/my_app.  thanks.

Comment: why would I get API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application?  I put in http://apps.facebook.com/mynamespace for the $canvas_page variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have "signed_request for Canvas" enabled in settings->advanced->migrations 
Then you should get the signed_request via $_POST.