# Is the Facebook canvas tutorial missing something?

Tags: canvas, facebook-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get an undefined index for signed_request in my facebook app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534241/why-do-i-get-an-undefined-index-for-signed-request-in-my-facebook-app)

I posted a question on the regular SO that is very similar but then found the facebook SO.

If I copy and paste this code from the [facebook canvas tutorial page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/):

```
 <?php 

     $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

     $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

How can I ever get the signed_request if the $auth_url is never called?  Or maybe I don't understand PHP.  It creates the $auth_url but never goes and gets it, so $signed_request is never populated.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  It is because I am stupid and was not accessing it via apps.facebook.com and instead going to http://mydomain.com...

Comment: FB.so is the same as SO.  Try adding/removing facebook. from the beginning of the url.

Comment: I don't know how to close my own question...

Answer (score 0):

The key bit is here:

```
if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
```

That creates a script element that that directs the browser to load the auth_url if the user session is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're browser isn't blocking that "top.location.href" javascript call? Try just echo/writeln the $auth_url for further inspection. If you could show us the "$auth_url" that it's retunring, that would/might help :)

Answer (score 0):

The '$auth_url' is only used to redirect the user in case he/she hasn't given permissions to your application.

The '$signed_request' is an encrypted data sent by facebook, the variable '$data' contains all this data decrypted as an associative array.

You don't need to care about '$signed_request' what you really need is in the '$data' variable which contains the user info that you probably will need.